# dynamic harmonic regression arima forecasts

Tags: forecasting, arima

I am trying to implement the dynamic harmonic regression Arima model in python.
I have the R code for it.
xreg <- forecast:::fourier(time_series, K = 1)
How can I implement the forecast:::fourier function in python? I am trying to implement the model for the M4 dataset (time series dataset).